# При валидации запроса на сервер получаю странные системные ошибки вместо своих кастомных сообщений

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

У меня есть такая вот модель для запроса на сервер:

```
 public class SaveRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("category")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Категория обязательна")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

В контроллере вызываю такое в самом начале:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

В качестве запроса передаю

```
{
    "category" : {"name" : "hello"}
}
```

А должен передать:

```
{
    "category" :  "hello"
}
```

Required выполняется. Но как задать собственное сообщение об ошибке, говорящее, что данные некорректны?

Я в ответ получаю системное сообщение от .NET о том, что он не может смапить:

> {"category":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'category', line 1, position 275.","After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: :. Path 'category', line 1, position 281."]}

А хотел бы получить что-то типа `{"status" : "error", "description": "Wrong data."}`

### Update

Я мог бы использовать аттрибут `[RegularExpression(@"регулярка тут") ]` но я не вижу у него возможности задать `ErrorMessage` параметр.

Comment: вы пытаетесь вот этот json `{"name" : "hello"}` распарсить в строку `string CategoryName { get; set; }` и получаете закономерную ошибку. До вашей вализации дело вообще не доходит.

Comment: Понятно, это объясняет то, что платформа ругается. Этого бы не было, если бы JSON приходил как строка. Но как мне задать кастомное сообщение для ошибки при парсинге в строку `CategoryName`?